# How to delete Item from ArrayList on another activity & update on previous activity?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity

I have an ArrayList I am sending item onItemClick On another activity from this:-

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MessageEmail.this, MessageByMessage.class);
            i.putExtra("msg_title", unreadMsgList.get(position).address);
            i.putExtra("full_msg",
                    unreadMsgList.get(position).unreadMessage);
            i.putExtra("pos", position);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

& get On another activity & set on text from this:-

```
title=getIntent().getExtras().getString("msg_title");
    message=getIntent().getExtras().getString("full_msg");
    position=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
    title_txt.setText(title);
    msg_txt.setText(message);
```

Now **Problem is that** I have a delete button in this activity. **I want to delete item on Button click  & will switch on my first activity Where List should be refresh**.
Thanks in advance!
Deepanker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StartActivityForResult(yourIntent,YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);` and on the `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case YOUR_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                yourArrayList.remove(theItemClicked);
                yourListview.notifySetDataChanged();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

in the otherActivity simply set some Result in an INTENT and finish() that Activity on Delete Button's OnClick Event.

Comment: on retun from 2nd activity i have got result ok=-1 & my starting result code is 0 what's the problem so contion not match resultCode==RESULT_OK

Answer (score 2):

There is a good example [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities) on how to communicate between activities. Basically you update the activity in the manifest and set `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. Then you handle the `onNewIntent` methode for the called activity.