# Keep a static variable throughout taking a picture and coming back

Tags: java, android, camera

On my on create function I give the location an ID. However my issue is when I go to add a photo to that page before I've saved it. I need to save the photo with the same ID as the page. So I create the ID on the on create then when i add a picture and come back as it's loaded the other intent it runs the code again and creates a new ID. How can I pass the ID through the photo and back.

The variable checkStationObjectID  is set at the top of the file.

Heres my on create:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_asset);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        Log.e("CamDebug", "Loading extras");
        if (extras != null) {   
            PreviousStationObjectID = extras.getString("StationObjectID");  
            editMode = extras.getBoolean("editMode");
            editAreaObjectID = extras.getString("editAreaObjectID");

        } 



        if(editMode){
            checkStationObjectID = editAreaObjectID;
             Log.e("CHECK ID - Edit mode", checkStationObjectID);

         } else {

            if(checkStationObjectID == null){
                checkStationObjectID = NewAssetStationObjectID;
                Log.e("CHECK ID = NEW ID", checkStationObjectID);
            } 

        }

       //Other items taken out



    }
```

I launch the camera with:

```
public void startCamera() 
{
    File photo = null;
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
               {
                   photo = new File(Global.Pictures + timestamp +".png");

               } 
    else 
               {
                   photo = new File(getCacheDir(), FOLDER_NAME+File.separator+timestamp+".png");
               }    
    if (photo != null) 
               {
                   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                   selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CALLBACK);
               }

}
```

Comment: You Can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177140/how-to-delete-item-from-arraylist-on-another-activity-update-on-previous-activ

Comment: Save as a preference , Load from a preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreate` is called whenever your application is started.  If you are calling another app like a camera, then the OS can kill your own `Activity` at any time while the camera `Activity` is running.  This could be to recover memory or resources that the running app needs.  Then when you exit the camera the OS will restart your `Activity`, which will call `onCreate` again.

I would suggest that you save the ID that you have generated into `SharedPreferences` just before you start the camera app.  Then check for a saved ID in `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to persist it you can create a Singleton object to act as a session and store the variable in there.. But I don't get why onCreate is executed again.. I thought the sub camera activity should return in onActivityResult? I pardon me if I misunderstood.

Or you can pass the var to the camera activity and pass it back when you are done with it.

Comment: I can't quite work out why the oncreate runs again when it passes the activity back. It's quite frustrating. I'm guessing I can just put a intent.putExtra("StationID", checkStationObjectID); on my startCamera() routine. However how do i pull that back from the onActiveityResult

Comment: Follow the other options to save in the preferences then.. The on create might be called when you have configuration change like orientation.. Or your activity might be killed but it should not be because it's waiting for a sub activity to complete unless the memory is too low..

Comment: You should handle the case where your activity is destroyed and recreated it should solve your problem.. Throw the variables in the bundle of ondaveinstancestate